# Bind a Class method on click of a dynamically created element coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, bind

I have a class Text that handle a text generated from an input and makes it customizable. For example, I have a class that creates color buttons based on the given colors array, here is the code:

```
    # Example of array of colors given to the function
    colors: 
        red : "255, 0, 0"
        blue : "24, 149, 207"
        green : "74, 165, 76"
        grey : "202, 202, 202"
        black : "0, 0, 0"
        yellow : "183, 118, 4"
        white : "255, 255, 255"
        purple : "83, 74, 166"

    # Here is the method that loop through colors, create a button for each of them and bind the on click event
    generateColorButtons: (colors) ->
        colorDiv = $('<div></div>',
            class : 'colors'
        )

        for color, rgb of colors
            button = $("<button></button>",
                class: color
            )

            # itemUniqueId is given to the class when instanciated
            button.on 'click', @txtColor(@itemUniqueId, rgb)
            button.appendTo colorDiv        

        return colorDiv

    # Here is the method that I call on click 
    txtColor: (id, color) ->
        $("#" + id + ' .addedTxt').css "color", "rgb(" + color + ")"
```

Clicking any of the color buttons gives me this error "***Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function***", I know that it is because it can't access the class method it is bound on, but is there a way to make it work or do I have to declare it as a regular function?

**UPDATE**

Turns out I just has to change a little bit my on click binding to make it work, here is the new class to generate the colors:

```
    # Loops through every color variables from the options to create a button for each of them
    generateColorButtons: (colors) ->
        colorDiv = $('<div></div>',
            class : 'colors'
        )

        for color, rgb of colors
            button = $('<button></button>',
                class: color
            )

            # Switched from 'on' to 'bind' and created the param to hold the rgb variable because I had scope problems and instead of calling directly the txtColor function, I created an anonymous function with the fat arrow to then call the txtColor in it.
            button.bind 'click', {param: rgb}, (event) =>
                @txtColor(@itemUniqueId, event.data.param)

            button.appendTo colorDiv


        return colorDiv
```

Comment: `on` expects a function, not `undefined` here `button.on 'click', @txtColor(@itemUniqueId, rgb)`

Comment: So there is no way to attach a method to a on click event even tho the buttons are generated from an instance of the class the method belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already figured this out but let me explain what went wrong and why you (think) you need the `{param: rgb}` parameter in your `button.bind` call.

Your original code said this:

```
button.on 'click', @txtColor(@itemUniqueId, rgb)
```

The `@txtColor(@itemUniqueId, rgb)` is a call to the `txtColor` method and that happens when the arguments to `button.on` are being built, i.e. it happens when you call `button.on` rather than when the click happens. That's the same as saying this:

```
x = @txtColor(@itemUniqueId, rgb)
button.on 'click', x
```

and that's clearly not what you want to do.

The obvious solution (and probably the next thing you tried) would be something like this:

```
button.on 'click', =>
    @txtColor(@itemUniqueId, rgb)
```

When you did that, you would discover that any click on any of the eight buttons would use the same RGB value and that RGB value would be the last one that the `for ... of` loop iterated over. Why would that happen? When you have something like this:

```
for k, v of obj
    f = -> v
    ...
```

each iterator will create a new function and leave it in `f` but (and this is a bit *but*) none of those functions will evaluate `v` until they're called. All the functions will do when they're built is store a reference to `v`, the value of `v` changes on each iterator but `v` is still the same variable. The result is that when the functions are called, they'll all end up using the same value for `v` and that value will be the last value `v` had in the iteration.

An example might useful. If you do this:

```
fns = for i in [0, 1, 2]
    -> i
for f in fns
    console.log f()
```

then you'll end up with three `2`s in your console. [**Demo**](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3afns%20=%20for%20i%20in%20%5B0,%201,%202%5D%0A%20%20-%3E%20i%0Afor%20f%20in%20fns%0A%20%20console.log%20f%28%29)

This problem is very common in (Java|Coffee)Script so CoffeeScript has a [solution specifically for this situation (end of this section)](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

You could use `do` to rewrite your loop like this:

```
for color, rgb of colors
    do (color, rgb) =>
        button = $('<button></button>', class: color)
        button.on 'click', =>
            @txtColor(@itemUniqueId, rgb)
        button.appendTo colorDiv
```

That forces `rgb` to be evaluated when the `do` is evaluated so you don't end up with the common reference problem.